# How do I get mod_rewrite working with TYPO3 and WordPress?

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, mod-rewrite, typo3

I've some trouble with TYPO3 (`mydomain.net`) and WordPress (`mydomain.net/blog/`) using mod_rewrite.

First I was running a TYPO3 installation which uses mod_rewirte without trouble.
Now I'm trying to run a WordPress too, but if WordPress uses mod_rewrite, every click of a link bing me back to the index of my TYPO3.

The filestructure of my FTP folder:

- `/html/` (contains the TYPO3 files and folders and the .htaccess-file)
- `/html/blog/` (contains the WordPress files and folders)

This is the content of the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(typo3|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|typo3conf|typo3temp|uploads|showpic\.php|favicon\.ico)/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^typo3$ typo3/index_re.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Any ideas as to what I should do? Or is it possible that only one CMS uses mod_rewrite?

Comment: Is there another htaccess under /html/blog? You can have many of them.

Comment: No, there isn't an other one. May I've to add a new one for wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a WordPress-specific `.htaccess` file in your `/blog/` directory by logging into the WordPress admin area, clicking 'Permalinks' (under the 'Settings' header), scrolling to the bottom of the page, and clicking 'Save Changes'.

This will force WordPress to create its default `.htaccess` file in your `/blog/` directory, which includes all mod_rewrite rules. If you see a message stating that the `.htaccess` file couldn't be created, copy the code in the error message and create the `.htaccess` file yourself. By default, the WordPress `.htaccess` rules should override the rules of your typo3 installation, so both CMSes should co-exist happily.

If you don't see an `.htaccess` file or an error message, create the [default .htaccess file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) manually containing the following, which specifies the subdirectory you installed WordPress in as `/blog/`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: If this still doesn't work the "Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer" Wordpress plugin can help you work out what rules are in place.

Comment: When I click 'Save Changes' under the 'Permanlinks'-Area, I don't get any .htaccess-file or errormessage. Isn't there an easy way to say somethink like: "If subdirectory 'blog', do this"? ;-)

Comment: @CrazyMetal Try following [these instructions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Creating_and_editing_.28.htaccess.29) to create the .htaccess file manually in your `/blog/` directory.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you all. I've added a new .htaccess-file in the subdirectory (followed Nicks instruction-link). Important: Don't forget to add the directory name in the file ;)

Comment: @Nick: The last directory name is still missing "RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]" ;)

Comment: @CrazyMetal Doesn't it work with the regular `. /index.php [L]`? I think you only need to declare the `/blog/` subdirectory on the `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: @Nick: No way, I just tested with ./index.php [L] and it will fire me back to the typo3 index.php. So the second directory is needed.